# how to add special character after few numbers in php

Tags: php

i have a small issue I want to add special character after **every 9 numbers**.
here is example

```
$new = "111222333444555666777888999";
```

now i want result something like this

```
$add_charcter = ($new, "//any method to add special character");
```

and result shouldbe like this

```
111222333-444555666-777888999
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: $string = substr_replace($new, "-", $position = 9, $length = 0);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ***shortest*** one with `preg_replace` function:

```
$new = "111222333444555666777888999";
$result = preg_replace('/.{9}(?!$)/', '$0-', $new);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
111222333-444555666-777888999
```

---

Regexp pattern elucidation:

- `.{9}` - match 9 characters
- `(?!$)` - negative lookahead assertion, ensures that matched 9-character sequence is not the last one to avoid adding special character at the end of the string

Answer (score 3):

Can use `str_split` and `implode`

- [`str_split`](http://php.net/str_split) — Convert a string to an array
- [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) — Join array elements with a string

Example:

```
$str = "111111111222222222333333333";
echo implode("-", str_split($str, 9)); // 111111111-222222222-333333333
```

Answer (score 2):

chunk_split() Can be used to split a string into smaller chunks.

```
 $new = "111222333444555666777888999";
 $result = chunk_split($new, 9, '-');
 echo rtrim($result,'-');
```

Comment: yes, but this will add the "-" to the end of the string.

Comment: sorry, i didn't noticed it, i edited the answer by using  rtrim() .